# RegEx for combining multiple sequences

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

As many people ,i am struggling with what it seems a "trivial" regex issue.
in a given text, whenever I encounter a word within {} brackets i need to extract it.At first i used

```
"\\{-?(\\w{3,})\\}"
```

and it worked ok:

as long as the word didnt have any white space or special character like ' .
For example {Project} returns Project.But {Project Test}  or {Project D'arce} don't return anything.
i know that for white characters i need to use \s.But it is absolutely not clear for me how to add to the above , i tried :

```
"%\\{-?(\\w(\\s{3,})\\)\\}"))
```

but not working.Also what if i want to add words containing a special characters like ' ??? Its really frustrating

Comment: You'll probably want to invert the part between the braces, e.g. to something like `\{([^}]{3,})\}`. That would match anything between a pair of curly braces. `[^}]` means "anything _except_ a closing curly brace. Note however, that this can become tricky and I'd think hard about allowing that much as this could lead to hard to find bugs if the requirements or data change. Why would you want to allow whitespace and special characters for the match in the first place? This gives the impression you want to parse code ... is that so?

Comment: Hi Thomas , thanks ,it works.Not really a code, but a text with "restrictions" to put it that way.But what if i need to put some restrictions, for example not allowing digits, or some sort of characters ?

Comment: Well, in that case you either list everything you don't want to allow (e.g. `[^\d}]` for an additional "no digits") or use a positive character class to list everything you want to allow, e.g. `[\w\s]` would mean any word character or whitespace. What you use depends on your requirements, e.g. whether you want to use blacklisting (disallow known chars) or whitelisting (only allow known chars).

Comment: Thanks Thomas ,Pshemo and others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[\w\s']`and add to it what you could allow to match:

```
\{-?([\w\s']{3,})}
```

In Java

```
String regex = "\\{-?([\\w\\s']{3,})}";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vj5Hp4/1)

If you want to prevent matching only 3 whitespace chars, you could use a repeating group:

```
\{-?\h*([\w']{3,}(?:\h+[\w']+)*)\h*}
```

About the pattern

- `\{` Match `{` char
- `-?` Optional hyphen
- `\h*` Match 0+ times a horizontal whitespace char
- `([\w\s']{3,})` Capture in a group matching 3 or more times either a word char, whitespace char or '
- `(?:\h[\w']+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching 1+ horizontal whitespace chars followed by what is listed in the character class
- `\h*` Match 0+ times a horizontal whitespace char
- `}` Match `}`

In Java

```
String regex = "\\{-?\\h*([\\w']{3,}(?:\\h+[\\w']+)*)\\h*}";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4eypfg/1)

Comment: You are welcome. If you don't want to match only whitespace chars, you could also use a repetition in a pattern like `\{-?\s*([\w']{3,}(?: [\w']+)*)\s*}`  https://regex101.com/r/vj5Hp4/2/

Answer (score 3):

How about matching any character inside `{..}` which is not `}`?

To do so you can use [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^..]` like `[^}]`. So your regex can look like

```
"\\{[^}]{3,}\\}"
```

But if you want to limit your regex only to some specific alphabet you can also use character class to combine many characters and even predefined [shorthand character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) like `\w` `\s` `\d` and so on.

So if you want to accept any word character `\w` or whitespace `\s` or `'` your regex can look like

```
"\\{[\\w\\s']{3,}\\}"
```

Comment: Hint: always play around here first before you start coding: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Mick While I like that site for other languages, I stopped using it for Java's regex. There ware too many differences at time when I made that decision (which was few ears ago, so maybe it got improved, I don't know). Also I am not the fan of making me escape every `/` with ``\/`` which is not necessary in Java.